# Magento 2: Override model not working

Tags: magento2, override-model

I am trying to override the `vendor/magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup/Model/GetPickupLocations.php` file

I have copied it to `app/design/frontend/Magento/child_theme/Magento_InventoryInStorePickup/Model/GetPickupLocations.php`

but it doesn't seem to work, have I copied it to the correct location?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override model (or extend) you should to create your own module in `app/code/VendorName/InventoryInStorePickup` where you define plugin or preference in `etc/di.xml` file.

Remember that using preferences and overwriting the entire model is not the best solution.

Why you want to override whole model? What you want to do?
Maybe all you need to do is create a plugin for an interesting method from GetPickupLocations model?

**First, take a look how to create basic module:**
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-module-in-magento-2/

**Next, read how to create plugin for interesting method**
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/

Comment: I have amended the original Magento GetPickupLocations.php file, rather than uploading it back to vendor/magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup/Model/ I wanted to copy it to my theme instead

Comment: You shouldn't edit the original files as you know. I would like to help you, but you didn't answer my questions. Read my answer and think about what you should do (plugin or preference).

Comment: I have had a quick look at the interception method, I will probably go down this route but will have a proper look in the morning. Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?